# What Kernel Threads are Responsible For Sending Network Packets in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I am reading the source code of Linux kernel trying to figure out how the Linux kernel sends the network packets, after many hours, I can only see the flow of network packets walking through TCP Layer, IP Layer and finally Datalink Layer, I can't find out which threads are doing these jobs.

My question is which kernel threads are responsible for sending network packets and where are they? (Since we can set a socket as non-blocking and let a user application to send network  packets as fast as possible, so when the network is busy there must be some queues to buffer these packets, and there must be some kernel threads running someplace sending these packets. )

Comment: Ask on http://kernelnewbies.org/

Answer (score 2):

By default, the kernel does not use threads to send network packets.

Good network chips manage a packet queue in hardware.
Cheaper chips have a fixed-length queue or no queue at all, and raise an interrupt when a packet has been transmitted; the kernel then enqueues or submits the next packet from its own queue from the interrupt handler.

The softirq for this is called `NET_TX_SOFTIRQ` (see `net/core/dev.c`).
If the kernel is under heavy load or configured to move work out of interrupts, the `ksoftirq/*` threads handle softirqs.

Comment: Supposing the send buffer of some socket is full at this moment, and the user process which owns this socket hung up. Minutes later when the network is free, who will take the packets out of the socket send buffer and resend them again? Isn't there kernel thread moving these packets to the packet queue in the chip? If there isn't, how the TCP layer knows when to resend packets of this socket?

Comment: The network chips raises an interrupt "when the network is free", i.e., when other packets have been handled.

Answer (score 0):

**The recv procedure:**

1. network chip recv data from wire
2. network chip put data into kernel's **RingBuffer** memory by DMA
3. network chip send hardware IRQ to cpu
4. cpu handle the top half of the IRQ, which is very fast, then generate a soft IRQ to ksoftirqd
5. kernel thread **ksoftirqd** close the hardware IRQ, then handle the bottom half of the soft IRQ

   5.1 ksoftirqd thread execute network driver's igb_poll() function, which take data from RingBuffer, then transfer through the tcp/ip stack. i.e., ip_rcv() -> tcp_rcv()..., finally put the data to socket buffer.

   5.2 ksoftirqd's work is done
6. user thread take data from the its socket buffer.

**The send procedure:**

Most work is handled by user thread in kernel state.
If user thread is resched, then the **ksoftirqd** thread do the remain work.